# Raspberry pi zero W LCD Display stays black after the boot

Tags: pi-zero-w, display, lcd

I installed Raspbian Os Lite 32 bit on a Raspberry pi zero w, when I turn it on with a 5in screen it shows the boot logs. But when it boots up (I can tell because it connects to my router), the screen stays black even that the rasp is up and running.

I can connect to it via ssh with no issue.

I'm using waveshare 4 inch HDMI LCD IPS Display ( [https://www.amazon.com/HDMI-LCD-Resolution-Resistive-Screen/dp/B07P5H2315/ref=sr_1_3?keywords=raspberry+pi+zero+w+touchscreen&sr=8-3](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B07P5H2315) )

One more information if it can be resourceful is that I'm powering the rasp and the LCD seperatly because I don't have the Rasp Header pins.

How can I troublshoot this ? ( I can tell that the HDMI is working because it showed the logs on the boot screen ).

Any Help could mean a lot, thank you!